# Point Cloud density visualization with PDAL

Tags: point-clouds, pdal

I have terrestrial laser scanning point cloud collected with scanners coordinate system. I would like to create density surface using [Pdal](https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/density/density.html#density) and running the following code in OSGeo4W shell. But getting error.

```
C:\>pdal density ^
More? /9A-1B_subset15m.las ^
More? -o /9A-1B_sub15m_den.sqlite ^
More? -f SQLite
(pdal density Error) GDAL failure (6) No translation for an empty SRS to PROJ.4 
format is known.
```

Generally, is it possible to use PDAL for Ground lidar processing with single return? I would like to create evenly distributed point cloud (thinning), extract bare ground, removing the noise.

Answer (score 0):

To the question of whether or not PDAL, generally speaking, can process ground lidar with single returns, the answer is yes. PDAL makes no assumptions as to whether or not multiple returns are available. (Some filters may be able to use the return information, but should either default to some other behavior or otherwise complain if return information is unavailable.)

As for your error, I would guess that the input LAS point cloud has no SRS assigned, and that this is required to create the SQLite output. If you know the SRS, you could assign it using `pdal translate` (or perhaps by setting `--readers.las.a_srs=<your SRS>` in the call to `pdal density`).